# how to download dataset in colab using torchvision iam getting this error

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

```
dataset = MNIST(root='data/', download=True)
Downloading http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz to data/MNIST/raw/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9432298eb00b> in <module>()
----> 1 dataset = MNIST(root='data/', download=True, transform=ToTensor())

11 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error. I think something must have changed on Yan LeCunn's side. You can fix with

```py
from six.moves import urllib
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```